# Game froze in <canvas> js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I`m writing a pong game on js and html using canvas. Besides main body of the game I have the starting menu with "play button"(all the buttons are just images i counted their coordinates and just use ), then next menu where user chooses the background and then eventually game itself and then after reaching 3 points by user or computer the game ends and there's a win or fail window appering where you can press the "back to menu" button and go back to the very first menu with "play button" and start everything again. Program does everything okay when you first launch it but after you for example lose and go back to main menu, choose the background, game starts aaaaaaand when ball reaches 2 points the game get frozen and sometimes after minute or so somehow loads the menu with backgrounds. I really have no idea what's wrong and why it gets frozen and strangely on the second time you play. Please help me ;((

PS. Im just a beginner idk how to insert the images here in stackoverflow

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("pongping");
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');


/////////////1)function to draw the rect
function drawPryamokutnik(x,y,w,h,color) {
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
}



//////////////////////2)рисуем круг ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function drawKolo(x,y,radius,color) {
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
}

///////////////////////3)drawText/////////////////////////////////////////////
function drawText(text,x,y,color){
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.font = "80px Arial";
    context.fillText(text,x,y);
}

///////////////////////4)создаем пластинку пльзователя//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const rectleft = {
    x:20,
    y:canvas.height/2-100,
    width: 25,
    height: 200,
    color: "WHITE",
    score:0
};


///////////////////////5)создаем пластинку компьютера//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const rectright = {
    x:canvas.width-45,
    y:canvas.height/2-100,
    width: 25,
    height: 200,
    color: "WHITE",
    score:0
};

///////////////////////6)создаем шайбу/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const ball = {
    x: canvas.width/2,
    y: canvas.height/2,
    speed: 5,
    radius: 20,
    velocityX: 5,
    velocityY: 5,
    colour:"WHITE"
};

//////////////////////8)создаем разделительную сетку///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


const net = {
    x:canvas.width/2-1,
    y:0,
    width: 2,
    height:10,
    color:"WHITE"
};


//////////////////////9)создаем функцию сетки/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function drawNet(){
    for(let i=0; i<=canvas.height;i+=15)
    {
        drawPryamokutnik(net.x,net.y+i,net.width,net.height,net.color)
    }
}
//drawPryamokutnik(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height, "BLACK");
//drawText("so you wanna die young?",200,300,"WHITE");


canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",moovePaddle);

function moovePaddle(etv){
    let rect=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    rectleft.y=etv.clientY-rect.top-rectleft.height/2;

}

function update(){
    ball.x += ball.velocityX;
    ball.y += ball.velocityY;
    let computerLevel= 0.1;
    rectright.y+=(ball.y-(rectright.y+rectright.height/2))*computerLevel;
    if (ball.y + ball.radius > canvas.height || ball.y - ball.radius < 0) {
        ball.velocityY = -1 * ball.velocityY;
    }
    let player = (ball.x>canvas.width/2)? rectright:rectleft;
    if(colission(ball,player)){
        let collidePoint = ball.y - (player.y + player.height / 2);
        collidePoint = collidePoint /(player.height / 2);
        let angleRead = Math.PI/4 * collidePoint;
        let direction = (ball.x < canvas.width / 2) ? 1 : -1;

        ball.velocityX = direction * ball.speed * Math.cos(angleRead);
        ball.velocityY = direction * ball.speed * Math.sin(angleRead);
        ball.speed += 1;
    }
    if (ball.x - ball.radius < 0 ){
        rectright.score++;
        ResetBall();
    }
    else  if(ball.x+ball.radius>canvas.width)
    {rectleft.score++;
        ResetBall();}
}

function ResetBall() {
    ball.x=canvas.width/2;
    ball.y=canvas.height/2;
    ball.speed=5;
    ball.velocityX=-ball.velocityX;

}

function colission(b,p){
    b.top=b.y-b.radius;
    b.bottom=b.y+b.radius;
    b.left=b.x-b.radius;
    b.right=b.x+b.radius;

    p.top=p.y;
    p.bottom=p.y+p.height;
    p.left=p.x;
    p.right=p.x+p.width;
    return b.right>p.left && b.bottom>p.top && b.left<p.right && b.top < p.bottom;
}

function render(){
    const back = new Image();
    if(backchek===1)
    {back.src = "back1.png";}
    if(backchek===2)
    {back.src = "back2.png";}
    if(backchek===3)
    {back.src = "back3.png";}
    context.drawImage(back, 0, 0);
    //drawPryamokutnik(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height,"BLACK");
    drawNet();
    drawText(rectleft.score,canvas.width/4,canvas.height/5,"WHITE");
    drawText(rectright.score,3*canvas.width/4,canvas.height/5,"WHITE");
    drawPryamokutnik(rectleft.x,rectleft.y,rectleft.width,rectleft.height,rectleft.color);
    drawPryamokutnik(rectright.x,rectright.y,rectright.width,rectright.height,rectright.color);
    drawKolo(ball.x,ball.y,ball.radius,ball.colour);
}

let slide;
function game() {
    slide=1;
    menu();
    if(startcheck===true)
    {backchoose();
        slide=2;
        if(backchek===1||backchek===2||backchek===3)
        {render();
        update();
            if(rectright.score>2)
            {
                losing();
                slide=3;
                // startcheck=false;
                if(backagain===true)
                {slide=1;
                    game();
                }}
            if(rectleft.score>2)
            {//startcheck=false;
                winning();
                slide=3;

                if(backagain===true)
                {slide=1;
                    game();
                }}
        }
    }
}


    let framePerSecond=65;
setInterval(game,1000/framePerSecond);


function menu(){
    const menuu = new Image();
    menuu.src = "menu.png";
    context.drawImage(menuu, 0, 0);
}

function losing(){
    const lose = new Image();
    lose.src = "lose.png";
    context.drawImage(lose, 0, 0);
}

function winning(){
    const win = new Image();
    win.src = "win.png";
    context.drawImage(win, 0, 0);
}

function backchoose(){
    const backk = new Image();
    backk.src = "back choose .png";
    context.drawImage(backk, 0, 0);
}
let backchek;
let backagain=false;
let startcheck=false;
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", clicked, false);

function clicked(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let rectt=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = e.clientX;
    const y = e.clientY - rectt.top;
    let xprtr;
    let yprtr;
    let hipot;
    let yby;
    let xby;
    let yey;
    let xex;
    if(x===496 && y===471&& slide===1)
    {startcheck=true;
        //backagain=false;
    }
    if(x>496){xprtr=x-496;}
    if(x<496){xprtr=496-x;}
    if(y>471){yprtr=y-471;}
    if(y<471){yprtr=471-y;}
    hipot=yprtr*yprtr+xprtr*xprtr;
    if(hipot<=10609&&slide===1)
    {startcheck=true;}
    if(slide===2&&(y>217&&y<430&&x>75&&x<404)){backchek=1;}
    if(slide===2&&(y>217&&y<430&&x>585&&x<924)){backchek=2;}
    if(slide===2&&(y>508&&y<773&&x>344&&x<675)){backchek=3;}
    if(slide===3&&y>519&&(y<702&&x>224&&x<768))
    {backagain=true;
        backchek=0;
        startcheck=false;
        rectright.score=0;
        rectleft.score=0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pong20</title>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="pongping" width="1000" height="800"></canvas>
 <script src="pongping.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does anything pop up in the console? That might give some hint as to what is going wrong.

I noticed that in your game() function you are recursively calling game(). This may cause a recursive overflow.
At the same time, you have setInterval calling game again and again. I recommend you delete the lines:

```
let framePerSecond=65;
setInterval(game,1000/framePerSecond);
```

and replace them with

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(game)
```

This will still initialize your game properly, but it will also not block the thread, so users can still interact with the page as expected. It may not keep the proper frame rate that you're expecting, but that function passes a timestamp to the function it calls, so you could keep track of the time since last call and update movements based on that. [Check out this example.](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-game-loop-in-javascript/)

then inside your game function, replace every call to

```
game()
```

with

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(game)
```

This will hopefully stop your game from crashing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: You may have to modify game() so that it always calls window.requestAnimationFrame(game) even if any of the 'if' statements are false

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: If you right click > inspect the window, then navigate to the console, are there any error messages or warnings?